# How to pass an object up to a view presented in a sheet in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, core-data, binding

I have a very basic application that lets me add Players to a List and store some values against them. The data is stored in CoreData and then displayed in a List. That all works fine but I want to be able to tap on the row in the List, show a new view presented in a sheet and then edit the existing entry and save it back to CoreData over the top of the existing entry.

I am really struggling with getting access to my selected Player and accessing it's properties and saving it back.

My Player struct looks like this:

```
struct Player: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let teamColor: String
    let startingWeight: Double
    let completionWeight: Double
}
```

I am currently using `onTapGesture` on the List to show a new view. I have an @State variable to handle the selected Player:

`@State private var selectedPlayer: Player?`

And I pass that through to the `EditPlayerView` into `@Binding var person: Player`

When I print that `person` variable out, it has the correct object that I've passed through but when I try to access its properties (.firstName, .lastName etc) I get an error:

`Cannot use instance member 'person' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available`

So I've had to put everything into a computed property, which just doesn't feel right:

```
var playerFirstName: String {
        return "\(person.firstName)"
        }
```

I haven't touched iOS stuff since 2014 with Objective-C where it was relatively easy to pass things up and down view hierachies so I'm assuming I am missing something or doing something massively wrong here as all I want to do is pass my Player object around and easily access it.

Any help would be appreciated

( I didn't add the full code for my creation of the player etc as that's all working as expected but can add more if it helps)

I've tried what's mentioned in the question - using Binding and State to pass the object and was expecting to be able to simply access `person.firstName` etc in the new view presented in a sheet but I cannot

UPDATE:

I'm adding additional code for context and assistance. My EditPlayerView:

```
    struct EditPlayerView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    @Binding var person: Player
            
    var playerFirstName: String {
        return "\(person.firstName)"
        }
    
    var playerLastName: String {
        return "\(person.lastName)"
        }
    
    var playerStartWeight: String {
        return "\(person.startingWeight)"
        }
    
    var playerCompletionWeight: String {
        return "\(person.completionWeight)"
        }
    
    var playerDetails: String {
        return "First Name: \(person.firstName)\nLast Name: \(person.lastName)\nStarting Weight: \(person.startingWeight)\nCompletion Weight: \(person.completionWeight)"
    }
    
    // State Variables
    @State private var selectedColor = Color.white
    @State private var amendedFirstName = ""
    @State private var amendedLastName = ""
    @State private var amendedStartWeight = ""
    @State private var amendedCompletionWeight = ""
             
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Section(header: Text("Existing Player Details")) {
                    Text(playerDetails)
                }
                Section(header: Text("Edit Details")) {
                    TextField("First Name", text: $amendedFirstName)
                    TextField("Last Name", text: $amendedLastName)
                    TextField("Start Weight", text: $amendedStartWeight)
                    TextField("Completion Weight", text: $amendedCompletionWeight)
                }
                Section {
                    Button(action: {
                        // TODO: Save the updated details to CD. 
                    }) {
                        Text("Save Updated Details")
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Edit Player")
        }
    }
}
```

An additional edit with my main view that adds the players:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \PlayerEntity.lastName, ascending: true)], animation: .default)
    
    private var players: FetchedResults<PlayerEntity>

    @State private var showingAddPlayerView = false
    @State private var showAlert = false
    
    @State private var alertTitle = ""
    @State private var alertMessage = ""
    @State private var alertButtonText = ""
    
    //NEW CODE
    @State private var selectedPlayer: Player?

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Section(header: Text("Add New Player")) {
                    Button(action: {
                       
                        showingAddPlayerView = true
                    }) {
                        Text("Add New Player")
                    }
                } // End of Section
                
                Section(header: Text("Participating Players")) {
                    /* Iterating through CoreData to create a "player" for each
                     record that we have */
                    ForEach(players, id: \.id) { playerEntity in
                                            let player = Player(firstName: playerEntity.firstName ?? "",
                                                                lastName: playerEntity.lastName ?? "",
                                                                teamColor: playerEntity.teamColor ?? "",
                                                                startingWeight: Double(playerEntity.startingWeight),
                                                                completionWeight: Double(playerEntity.completionWeight))
                        /*NavigationLink(destination: EditPlayerView()) {
                                        Text("Edit Player Details")
                                    }*/
                        AddPlayerPlayerRow(player: player)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                print(player)
                                //showAlert = true
                                self.alertTitle = "Player Detals"
                                self.alertMessage = "Player: \(player.firstName) \(player.lastName)\nStart Weight: \(player.startingWeight)\nCompletion Weight: \(player.completionWeight)\nTeam Colour: \(player.teamColor)"
                                self.alertButtonText = "Dismiss"
                                
                                // Pass the tapped on player object into the selectedPlayer binding variable
                                // This is so we can use it in our new view
                                selectedPlayer = player
                                
                                
                            }
                            .sheet(item: $selectedPlayer) { person in
                                EditPlayerView(person: Binding.constant(person))
                            }
                            .alert(isPresented: $showAlert) {
                                        Alert(title: Text(alertTitle), message: Text(alertMessage), dismissButton: .default(Text(alertButtonText)))
                                    }
                            
                    } // End of ForEach
                    .onDelete(perform: deletePlayers)
                } // End of Section
                
                #if DEBUG
                Section(header: Text("DEBUG")) {
                    Button("Print Data") {
                                    for player in players {
                                        print(player.firstName ?? "")
                                        print(player.lastName ?? "")
                                        print(player.teamColor ?? "")
                                        print(player.startingWeight)
                                        print(player.completionWeight)
                                    }
                                }
                } // End of Section
                #endif
                
            } // End of List
            .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
            .navigationTitle("MvF North Tyneside")
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
        } // End of NavigationView
        .sheet(isPresented: $showingAddPlayerView) {
            AddPlayerView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, viewContext)
        }
    }
    
    // ############### END OF MAIN CONTENT VIEW ##########################
    
    // ############### START OF ADD NEW PLAYER VIEW ######################
    
    // This is shown when we press the "Add New Player" button
    struct AddPlayerView: View {
        @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
        @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode

        // State Variables
        @State private var selectedColor = Color.white
        @State private var playersFirstName = ""
        @State private var playersLastName = ""
        @State private var playersStartingWeight = ""
        @State private var playersCompletionWeight = "0.0"
    
        @State private var showAlert = false
        
        var body: some View {
            NavigationView {
                Form {
                    Section(header: Text("Personal Information")) {
                        TextField("First Name", text: $playersFirstName)
                        TextField("Last Name", text: $playersLastName)
                        TextField("Starting Weight", text: $playersStartingWeight)
                            .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                        TextField("Completion Weight", text: $playersCompletionWeight)
                            .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                    } // End of Section
                    Section(header: Text("Team Colour")) {
                        CustomColorPicker(selectedColor: $selectedColor)
                    } // End of Section
                    Section {
                        Button(action: {
                            if playersLastName.isEmpty || playersLastName.isEmpty || playersStartingWeight.isEmpty || playersCompletionWeight.isEmpty {
                                showAlert = true
                                
                            } else {
                                savePlayer()
                            }
                        }) {
                            Text("Save Player")
                        
                        }
                        .alert(isPresented: $showAlert) {
                                    Alert(title: Text("Input Error"), message: Text("Please make sure that all fields are filled out"), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
                                }
                    }
                }
                .navigationTitle("Add Player")
            } // End of Navigation View
        }

         private func savePlayer() {
             
            guard let startingWeight = Double(playersStartingWeight) else { return }
            guard let completionWeight = Double(playersCompletionWeight) else { return }
            
            // Let's get a hex string from our selected color
            let uiColor = UIColor(selectedColor)
            let hexStringFromChosenColour = uiColor.hexString
    
            /* What is entered into the Add Player form is then mapped
             to the CoreData PlayerEntity model */
            let newPlayer = PlayerEntity(context: viewContext)
            newPlayer.id = UUID()
            newPlayer.firstName = playersFirstName
            newPlayer.lastName = playersLastName
            newPlayer.teamColor = hexStringFromChosenColour
            newPlayer.startingWeight = startingWeight
            newPlayer.completionWeight = completionWeight

            do {
                try viewContext.save()
                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            } catch {
                let nsError = error as NSError
                print("[DEBUG] Error saving: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }

    private func deletePlayers(offsets: IndexSet) {
        withAnimation {
            offsets.map { players[$0] }.forEach(viewContext.delete)

            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                print("[DEBUG] Error deleting: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be better to look at more source code of your example, especially at `EditPlayerView` and it's init method. Maybe you do not even need to use `Binding` for this task.

Comment: Thanks, Tikhon. Yeah, I have a feeling I'm doing something horrendously wrong and it will be an easy fix once I understand the problem. I've added my EditPlayerView

Comment: I think instead of `@Binding var person: Player` you can use just `let person: Player`. But I do not understand why is the error thrown, can you attach view with the list too?

Comment: @TikhonPetrishchev I've tried using `let person: Player` but it throws errors as well.

Comment: I've added my code that adds a player and adds to Core Data etc

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce your issue. I just created blank SwiftUI project, pasted your code and run. In the `EditPlayerView` the "Existing Player Details" are shown as expected. After that I copied `playerDetails` string and paste it into `Text` instead of `playerDetails` computed property: `Text("First Name: \(person.firstName)\nLast Name: \(person.lastName)\nStarting Weight: \(person.startingWeight) etc.")` and it also works fine. Then I replaced `@Binding var person: Player` with `let person: Player` and it works too. Maybe i misunderstood your problem?

Comment: Which lines where you are trying to access `Player` properties causes an error?

Comment: Yeah, my code there is "hacky" to get around the problem. As I mentioned in the original question, I've had to use computed properties to get access to firstName, lastName etc in the EditPlayerView. I don't feel I should have to do that if I'm passing an object up the view, I should be able to do just `person.firstName` without having to wrap everything as a computed property.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the Player struct and use the auto-generated model class or generate one with the model editor so you have:

```
class Player: NSManagedObject {
```

And define in `EditPlayerView` as:

```
@ObservedObject player: Player
```

Comment: The problem is that the player in `ContentView` must be optional, since at the time when `ContentView` being created, there is no player being selected. Only when user tap on a cell, we set player, and this player will be passed to sheet. `@ObservedObject`not allow player being an optional

Comment: The way to not allow it to be optional is with a conditional view. You can create one using if in body.

Comment: Another way is with sheet(item:)